# C# Denied Access Deleting Registry Value

Tags: c#, registry

When attempting to create a RunOnStartup Function that checks weather or not a key exists and if it does, does the user want it deleted, I encounter the problem of Access Denied. More specifically this.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Cannot write to the registry key.'
```

My code for this here.

```
private static void RunOnStartup()
    {
        string KeyName = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
        string valueName = "MyApp";
        if (Registry.GetValue(KeyName, valueName, null) == null)
        {
            RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            reg.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("The Program will now start on startup", "Startup");
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("This Program can already run on Start up. Do you want it to no longer do so?", "Start Up", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run").DeleteValue("MyApp");
            }
            else if(dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Program will continue to run on Startup", "Startup", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

I can create the key, Just not delete it, quite strange. Perhaps there is a permission I'm missing, I attempted to run in administrative mode but the same thing happened.

Comment: Isn't there a logic flaw in your code? `keyName` points to the HKLM hive while you try to delete from HKCU. I didn't try this but maybe the exception is also thrown if the value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two errors in your code:

- The exception `UnauthorizedAccessException` - 'Cannot Write to the registry key' indicates that the you didn't open the `RegistryKey` in `writable` mode. Instead you should open it in write mode before trying to delete. Make sure you pass `true` as the second argument, like this:

  ```
  RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\..", true);
  reg.DeleteValue("MyApp");
  ```
- Also initially your `KeyName` and `if` condition check in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` whereas your insertion/deletion later refer to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` using `Registry.CurrentUser` so you should probably make them consistent.

  ```
  string KeyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
  ```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I did both of your suggestions and  it worked, but it wouldn't if i had only done one, So Thank you!