# C# registry Can't delete MachineGuid access denied

Tags: c#, registry

Here's my code:

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
var HKLM = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Cryptography");
HKLM.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
```

Problem: Even when I run it as an administrator; it will just give me an error that saying:

> Cannot write to the registry key.

I can't delete anything in the local machine folder.

edit: I fixed it by unchecking "Prefer 32bit". or by checking if process is a 32 or 64bit application.

Comment: Why you have `\\ ` in your key when you are using `@`?

Comment: not sure.......

Comment: Possible duplicates: [C# Denied Access Deleting Registry Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43816430/4519059) ;).

Comment: I fixed it by unchecking "Prefer 32bit". or by checking if process is a 32 or 64bit application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the RegistryKey to be writable if you want the write access.

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",true);
```

Comment: RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
            using (var key = reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", true)) // writeable
            {
                key.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
            

Still doesnt work.

Comment: using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", true)) // writeable
            {
                key.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
            }